# automate color pick for the stacked bar plots

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

below is my example jsfiddle, of what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwvhhe3o/

1. How to pass color range instead of manually entring the hexa codes ?

I tried passing color values as

```
var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
 var colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(colorRange.range());
```

and then, `.attr("fill", colorRange );` to respective fill. However, did not suceed.

2. I pass the legend values as a variable, is there a way to automate the case switch? Any alternative way to case switch.

I have too many legend names to manually name them. an example below

```
 legend.append("text")
       .attr("x", width + 5)
       .attr("y", 9)
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .style("text-anchor", "start")
       .text(function(d, i) { 
        switch (i) {
        case 0: return "Anjou pears";
        case 1: return "Naval oranges";
        case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
        case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
        case 4: return "cherries";
        case 5: return "plum";
        case 6: return "grapes";
        case 7: return "melons";
       }
    });
```

Any direction or suggestion to achieve the above task is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ve38098w/

All you need to do is create a new color scale

```
var colors = d3.scale.category20()
```

Associate each layer point with a fruit

```
var keys = ["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears", "cherries", "plum","grapes", "melons"]

var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(keys.map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit], name: fruit};
  });
}));
```

And then start passing in fruit names during the data join.

```
var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  ...
  .style("fill", d=> colors(d.name))
```

The first time you pass in `"apple"` like `var randomColor = colors('apple')`, apple will be assigned a color. The next time you pass in apple, you will retrieve the same color.

For the legend, do adata join to create the rectangles, using the previously discussed color scale.

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(keys)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", d=>colors(d));

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(d=>d);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is perfect. What does `d3.scale.category20()` do ? create 20 colors? What to do if my legend items would be for instance 100, does the color scheme scales automatically to accommodate based on the `count` of legends ? one more thing, the tool tip works on fiddle displaying the count...but does not work on my browser ? I'm i missing something ?

Comment: Thank you for the stepwise explanation, it is really helpful

Comment: is there a way to add scroll bar to legend and horizontal scroll  for a fixed with plot ?

Comment: There are several color scales with preset colors, you can view them in the documentation. If you have more items than colors, the scale will start recycling colors. Jsfiddle is run on a browser, so i'm not sure what the problem is. The only way i know to get scrollbars in SVG is to use `foreignObject`

Comment: what is `foreignObject` ? can you provide a documentation or example to try ?

Comment: `foreignObject` is an element that can contain html elements. So if you put a `div` into a `foreignObject` into `svg`, your div can scroll. I suggest you just google `foreignObject`.